# Как сделать меню на CSS?

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток! Есть задача сделать меню на css. Вчера весь день просидел и не смог сделать задумку. Вот внешний вид меню

[image]

Сильно не пинайте, в верстке пока новичек.

Comment: @alexfedosienko, Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Думаю, что для начала надо сделать две вещи: 1) Определиться с тем, как распределяется ширина компонента меню. Всем по 20% или, скажем, по 100px. 2) Набросать хотябы какую-нибудь стртовую версию общей разметки и поазать. Используйте сервис: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NMJUs/12/ Пока сделано только вот это

Answer (score 2):

Есть два способа выстроить два элемента друг за другом:

**display: inline;** Но на самом деле лучше **display: inline-block;** необходимую "строчность" элемента вы получите, но так же остануться и некоторые особенности блочности: возможность задавать ширину, пэддинги и т.д.

**float: left;** Обычное обтекание. Этот способ мне нравиться больше. Любой обтекаемый элемент делается блочным. Между блочными элементами не появляются пробелы. Хотя бы по этому я нахожу его более уместным. Но у обтекания больше особенностей. Например то, что обтекание надо сбрасывать. Делается это свойством clear: both; (сразу и левое и правое обтекание). Тег с таким свойством должен идти после последнего обтекаемого элемента. Чтобы не засорять HTML лишними тегами, рекоменду добавить в код класс clearfix (смотрите код) и просто добавлять его родительскому оберточнуму тегу. При помощи псевдоклассов before и after добавляются нужные элементы со сбросом обтекания.

http://jsfiddle.net/NMJUs/13/

Первый и последний элементы совсем не нужно унифицировать в html. Вы можете использовать псевдоклассы CSS:

```
.menu li:first-child {

}

.menu li:last-child {

}
```

Скруглить углы попробуйте при помощи свойства [border-radius](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-radius).

Самим элементам li добавьте ширину в 20%.

Ссылки внутри элементов сделайте блочными (display: block), чтобы они заняли всю ширину элемента.

**UPD1:**

1) Есть очень удобный сервис для вставки случайных картинок: **[lorempixel.com](http://lorempixel.com)**. Берем с него ссылку типа: **http://lorempixel.com/20/20/people** - и это прямая ссылка размера 20х20 на картинку из категории people. Вставляйте вместо иконок соц. сетей.

2) Рекомендую для меню навигации использовать ul / li. А для меню действий использовать menu / li. Навигационному меню принято выставлять класс **.nav** или **.navigation**.

3) Когда вы раскидываете несколько компонентов, типа li, с содержимым img, то все, что касается разметки, например margin или размеры, применяйте к li.

4) Фон пропал потому что не сбросили отекание. Добавьте оберточному тегу кмпонентов меню класс clearfix.

5) Если сами меню вы раскидываете при помощи обтекания то их обертке (background) так же добавьте этот clearfix.

6) И побольше логики в коде. Пишите селекторы друг за другом, по смысловому порядку.

Comment: получилось вот это http://jsfiddle.net/NMJUs/36/
Только не работает фон у класса background.

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте шрифт, градиент можно сделать [тут](http://gradients.glrzad.com/) и, как уже написали, border-radius.

**edit**:
там еще тень есть, [тут можно сделать](http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/)

Comment: Для градиента рекомендую http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ т.к. там нотация использованная в фотошопе.

Comment: Да, а "стэк" шрифтов можно получить, скажем, тут: http://cssfontstack.com/

Comment: да, спасибо за градиент, должен быть выбор

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/NMJUs/39/